# InvalidSyntax on Python IF statement

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax

I can't figure out what's wrong below... keep getting syntax error on the IF statement.

```
#Specify a key file
keyfile="C:\Python27/keepasskey"

try:
 debug = Debug()

if os.path.isfile(keyfile):
 print "[+] Keyfile Loaded: '" + keyfile + "'"
 aProcess = debug.execv(['KeePass.exe', 'Database.kdb', '-keyfile:' + keyfile, '-pw:'.ljust(WORD_SIZE+4)])
else:
    print "[+] Specified keyfile '" + keyfile + "' does not exist, ignoring argument"
    aProcess = debug.execv( ['KeePass.exe', 'Database.kdb', '-pw:'.ljust(WORD_SIZE+4)])
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your `try` needs an `except`. Also, you should make your indentation consistent throughout the module.

Answer (score 2):

You need to indent your `if` statement so that it's probably within the scope of the `try` statement or else you need to put in a `except` after the `try` but before the `if`. Like so:

```
try:
  debug = Debug()
  if os.path.isfile(keyfile):
    print "Indentation is required and part of the language syntax"
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked but now I'm facing a different issue. This is the full code I'm trying to run [link]http://blog.q-protex.com/2010/03/14/keepass-self-bruteforce/#comment-261[/link]

Comment: When running the code I get 

`code

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\winappdbg\win32\defines.py", line 120, in
RaiseIfZero
    raise ctypes.WinError()
WindowsError: [Error 2] can't find the specified file..`

Comment: @user3534160 Open a new Question with the code you're using and the exception you're seeing and let's see if we can't fix it.

Comment: Thank you. I've opened a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23164337/facing-problems-while-running-a-python-script-to-brute-force-keepassx