# Facing problems while running a Python script to brute-force KeePassX

Tags: python, passwords, brute-force

I've been trying for awhile to run the following script as an attempt to recover a KeePassX password, problem is that a lot of programming issues keeps coming up everytime I try to run it and since I'm not a programmer sometimes (even after researching) it's really hard to find what's wrong...

I would really appreciate any help to successful run this script:

```
from winappdbg import Debug
from time import strftime
import time
import os.path

counter=0
word=""
words=[]
r_eax=0
r_ecx=0
r_edx=0

WORD_SIZE = 20

#Save the state of the registers
def action_0(event):
 global r_eax, r_ecx, r_rdx
 aThread = event.get_thread()
 r_eax = aThread.get_register("Eax")
 r_ecx = aThread.get_register("Ecx")
 r_edx = aThread.get_register("Edx")
#Write the word
def action_1( event ):
 global word
 global words
 global counter
 global WORD_SIZE

 aThread = event.get_thread()
 aProcess = event.get_process()
 memDir = aThread.get_register("Ecx")
 word=words[counter]
 word = word.replace("\n","")
 word = word[0:WORD_SIZE-1]
#word = word.lower() #optional
 aProcess.poke(memDir,word + "\0")
#Check the flag state
def action_2( event ):
 global word
 global counter
 aThread = event.get_thread()
 b = aThread.get_flag_value(aThread.Flags.Zero)
 if b:
  print 'Counter: ' + repr(counter) + ' - Correct: ' + word
  event.get_process().kill()
 else:
  print 'Counter: ' + repr(counter) + ' - Incorrect: ' + word

  if counter&lt:
   len(words)-1
   counter+=1
   aThread.set_register("Eip", 0x004D6699)
  else:
   event.get_process().kill()
#Restore the registers to the original state
def action_3( event ):
 aThread = event.get_thread()
 aThread.set_register("Eax",r_eax)
 aThread.set_register("Ecx",r_ecx)
 aThread.set_register("Edx",r_edx)
 aThread.set_register("Eip", 0x004DC395)
#Specify a dictionary here
words = open('dic.txt', "r").readlines()
print "[+] Words Loaded: ",len(words)

#Specify a key file
keyfile = "key"

try:
  debug = Debug()
  if os.path.isfile(keyfile):
    print "[+] Keyfile Loaded: '" + keyfile + "'"
    aProcess = debug.execv(['KeePass.exe', 'keepassdb.kdb', '-keyfile:' + keyfile, '-pw:'.ljust(WORD_SIZE+4)])
  else:
   print "[+] Specified keyfile '" + keyfile + "' does not exist, ignoring argument"
  aProcess = debug.execv( ['KeePass.exe', 'keepassdb.kdb', '-pw:'.ljust(WORD_SIZE+4)])

#Set the breakpoints
  debug.break_at(aProcess.get_pid() , 0x004DC395, action_0)
  debug.break_at(aProcess.get_pid() , 0x004D77A0, action_1)
  debug.break_at(aProcess.get_pid() , 0x004D6684, action_2)
  debug.break_at(aProcess.get_pid() , 0x004DC39A, action_3)

#Wait for the debugee to finish
  t1 = time.clock()
  debug.loop()

finally:
 debug.stop()

print 'Finished in ' + repr(time.clock() - t1) + ' seconds!'
```

When running the script I get:

```
C:\Python27>python.exe force.py
[+] Words Loaded:  5
[+] Keyfile Loaded: 'key'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "force.py", line 86, in <module>
    aProcess = debug.execv(['KeePass.exe', 'keepassdb.kdb', '-keyfile:' + keyfile
, '-pw:'.ljust(WORD_SIZE+4)])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\winappdbg\debug.py", line 317, in execv
    dwParentProcessId = dwParentProcessId)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\winappdbg\debug.py", line 371, in execl
    dwParentProcessId = dwParentProcessId,
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\winappdbg\system.py", line 1259, in start_
process
    lpStartupInfo   = lpStartupInfo)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\winappdbg\win32\defines.py", line 164, in
__call__
    return self.fn_ansi(*argv, **argd)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\winappdbg\win32\kernel32.py", line 2630, i
n CreateProcessA
    _CreateProcessA(lpApplicationName, lpCommandLine, lpProcessAttributes, lpThr
eadAttributes, bool(bInheritHandles), dwCreationFlags, lpEnvironment, lpCurrentD
irectory, ctypes.byref(lpStartupInfo), ctypes.byref(lpProcessInformation))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\winappdbg\win32\defines.py", line 120, in
RaiseIfZero
    raise ctypes.WinError()
WindowsError: [Error 2] O sistema nÒo pode encontrar o arquivo especificado. >>> which means file not found in portuguese.
```

Note: The script was copied from http://blog.q-protex.com/2010/03/14/keepass-self-bruteforce/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems like you're missing an installation of KDB? Does the script say you need to be using KDB? That or it's a Windows bug so it's out of my  realm of expertise. Sorry can't help.

Comment: These are the only requirements that I had to install:

python 2.6.4 (2.6.x should also work), and
winappdbg-1.3.win32. When you say 'KDB' you mean winappdbg?  Appreciate your help.